# why is the gridspace shared in my dynamic bootstrap pills?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

In the code below, for some reason when I switch to the 'experience' tab the gridspace used by 'home' is used while the 'home' content is hidden. Where exactly did I go wrong in my code?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="tab-content">
  <div id='home' class='class="tab-pane fade in active' style='text-align: center;'>
    <div class='container'>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3'>
          <div class='panel panel-primary' style='text-align: left;'>
            <div class="panel-heading">
              debug
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body">
              temp
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div id="experience" class="tab-pane fade">
    test
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is your Problem:

```
<div id='home' >>>>>>class='class="<<<<<tab-pane fade [...]
```

in HTML you should use " " instead of ' ', furthermore.

Fix this, and it will work ;)
http://www.bootply.com/WuGW32sWwn

Comment: omg thank you so much, I can't believe that was my problem all along